# How to move Z-axis to a specificic position (Z-max) after printing?

Tags: marlin, z-axis

I have a Cartesian printer in a cubic format (the bed moves vertically) with Marlin 2.x

I am not finding a way to make it move to Z-max (23 cm) when finishing the printing.

The idea is to lower the bed all the way to the max, to make easy removal of the printed piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the bed down, you simply instruct the bed to do so after the print.

The best way to do that is add a G-code line to your "end G-code" script you find in your slicer you use.

Just add the line:

```
G1 Z230 F500
```

With this command you instruct the bed to lower to your maximum Z height at speed (feed rate) 500 mm per minute.